# LibreOffice screws up formulas after saving to .doc format

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, libreoffice-math

When I add a formula, change its font and size, and then save to two formats - **.odt** and **.doc**, the formula in **.odt** looks the same as it was before saving, but the formula in **.doc** becomes compressed and diminished, and its settings aren't saved. What's wrong with it?

[A formula in **.odt**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/576MZ.png)

[A formula in **.doc**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpDU8.png)

Comment: Libreoffice native format (.odt) is not 100% compatible with Word native format (.doc).

Comment: What version of LibreOffice are you using?  5.4.2 was released in the last week or so.  If you have 5.4.1 then it may not solve the issue, but your version could be super old.

Comment: @cybernard, 5.4.2.2